# Cocos2d v3 alternative to SpriteKit SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromPath

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone, sprite-kit

I'm trying to migrate a game from spriteKit to Cocos2d v3. Game is a topDown racing that uses some bezier curves to draw the outline of the tracks.This curves are transformed in physics objects with the method:

```
[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromPath:CGPathRef]
```

I must use this method and i can't use a tile map layer physics because i wanna a smooth and realistic reaction when my car collides with the border of the track (i don't want the "squared" logic of a tiled map.). The system works but in Iphone 4 i have some performance troubles... Seems impossible to resolve this problems so i decide to migrate my project from SpriteKit to Cocos2d V3 to try if i can manage better the game camera logic...Anyway the first problem that i have encountered is to transform my outline shaped tracks in physicis body. How i can translate this code for Cocos2D?

```
UIBezierPath* bezier2Path = UIBezierPath.bezierPath;
[bezier2Path moveToPoint: CGPointMake(1621.33, 145.12)];
[bezier2Path addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(1825.33, 350.46) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(1838, 145.12) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(1825.33, 350.46)];
[bezier2Path addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(1825.33, 731.12) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(1825.33, 350.46) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(1825.33, 540.46)];
[bezier2Path addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(1640.67, 928.46) controlPoint1: 
[bezier2Path closePath];

 RaceTrack.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromPath:[self bezier2Path.CGPath]];
```

Answer (score 0):

In cocos2d an alternative of bodyEdgeLoopFrom not exist.